# Iterate through all byte values -128-127 without casting in Java

Tags: java, performance, iteration

I need to iterate through all byte values (-128 to 127 inclusive). I could use an `int` iterator, but then I have to cast each time to `byte`. Using a `byte` iterator has the problem that I can't test for `b < 128` as it will overflow. I thought of using a while loop and doing the test before incrementing, which is my best solution so far. Is there a better approach?

Comment: In Java, byte is a signed value. You actually get from -128 to 127, so the logic "byte < 256" is flawed.

Comment: Java doesn't have unsigned types, so a `byte` is -128..127.  You'll need to use a wider type.  As annoying as it may be, that's the way the fathers of Java chose to go.

Comment: why do you object to the cast?

Comment: @Alex, fvu: Yeah, sorry I meant -128..127. Will edit.

Comment: Its worth nothing that the loop is so short the JIT might not even compile it to native code. This will make it much slower than anything else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java bytes are signed so they have the values -128 to 127. Anyway, you shouldn't worry about casts and extra checks like that because they are trivial to optimize away. In fact, at the JVM level, there's no such thing as a byte variable. It's treated as an int anyway.

Comment: It just feels like there must be a better approach to this. Well, I'll go with this / the while loop for now. Interested to see if there's a better answer.

Comment: I didn't down vote this, but the "strictly speaking" is not strictly correct.  Sure, there aren't bytecodes for doing `byte` operations, but bytecode verifier, interpreter and JIT compiler DO know the true type of variables, and DO make use of this information.  In the latter case, it *could* affect the generated native code for handling byte-typed variables.

Comment: @Stephen Having read the JVM specification, the source code for the Hotspot type verifier, and actually tested it myself, I can assure you that this is not the case. The only time that booleans, bytes, chars, and shorts are treated differently is when being stored in arrays or a field.

Comment: Have you also read the source code for the JIT compiler and checked that it doesn't generate different native code?

Comment: @Stephen The fact that it allows full 32bit values to be passed as byte arguments is a pretty good indication that it isn't generating different code. And in the case of local variables, there's no such thing as a byte variable at the bytecode level in the first place.

Comment: @Antimony - Your argument is not convincing.  The full type information >>is<< available to the JIT, even if the bytecode instruction set is agnostic.  The only way to be sure is to either look at the JIT source code, or examine the generated NATIVE code across a range of testcases.  (And the reason that the verifier doesn't need to be aware of this is that you can't break the JVM execution model by treating a `boolean` as an `int` or vice-versa.)

Comment: Well if you don't believe me it's your loss. There's no real point in trying to convince you further.

Answer (score 3):

> Using a byte iterator has the problem that I can't test for b < 128

Test for `b == 127` as the loop termination condition.

However, I agree with Antimony that it probably makes no difference whether you use `int` or `byte` from a performance perspective.  At the bytecode level, the JVM only provides 32 and 64 bit integer arithmetic operators.

At the language level I think that the typecast will be happening in the `byte` case as well as the `int` case.  Consider that `b++` is actually equivalent to

```
    byte b = ...;
    b = (byte) (b + 1);
```

and that the typecast is not a noop because `b + 1` produces an `int` value.  So

```
    for (byte b = -128; b != 127; b++) {
        ...
    }
```

has a notional typecast in it.  Whether this means anything from a performance perspective is debatable, because the JIT does a lot of work to optimize away unnecessary operations when generating native code.

---

Finally, standard points about micro-optimization in Java:

- If you haven't profiled the code already, there is a good chance that you are wasting your time trying to tune something that doesn't matter.
- You should be relying on actual measurements (i.e. benchmarking YOUR application) rather than intuition or advice on what is faster.  Be prepared to have your intuition proven wrong.
- Even if you do manage to get an appreciable speedup by micro-optimization, beware that the speedup is likely to be platform specific.  Indeed, an improvement on one platform may be a slowdown on another platform.

Comment: Testing for b != 127 means that the loop won't iterate for b == 127.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `b <= 127`?

Comment: @Duncan that would then cause an overflow when b gets incremented at 127 and will become -128, so you would have an endless loop